# Laravel blade "Call to a member function has() on array"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

controller:

```
session(['errors' => ['email' => ['The email is invalid.']]]);
return view('auth.login');
```

blade:

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
   <span class="help-block">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
   </span>
@endif
```

error:

> Call to a member function has() on array

I have tried (object) before array, return view()->with() and much more!!
But I always get this error!!

If possible I dont want to change the blade file!! Is there anyway to send that data from controller in the right way??

Comment: why put `errors` in the session instead of passing `errors` to the view you are rendering?

Comment: I was doing that before, but got same error! What I want to do is get the errors using ->has(), ->any(), ->all()...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$errors returned by Validator is an instance of Illuminate\Support\MessageBag and not an array;

To replicate the usage:
In your controller, you can:

```
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

// Create a new MessageBag instance in your method.
$errors = new MessageBag;

// Add new messages to the message bag.
$errors->add('email', 'The email is invalid.');

return view('auth.login', ['errors' => $errors]);
```

I reckon you should use another variable name like $customErrors in your blade template, just to make sure you can use view('view')->withErrors($validator) in future if required, because withErrors pass variable $errors to view tempalte.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages